# Deploy Angular 17 to AWS Serverless

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, deployment, serverless

I created a brand new Angular 17 Standalone application. Created two components with simple routes.
I installed the following

```
npm i -S aws-serverless-express

npm i -D serverless serverless-api-compression serverless-apigw-binary serverless-associate-waf serverless-offline
```

I tried to deploy it to AWS Serverless lambda using the following serverless.yml file

```
service: seventeentest-app

plugins:
  - serverless-apigw-binary
  - serverless-api-compression
  - serverless-associate-waf
  - serverless-offline

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs20.x
  stage: dev
  region: ap-south-1
  memorySize: 512
  timeout: 10

functions:
  api:
    handler: lambda.universal
    events:
      - http: ANY /{proxy+}
      - http: ANY /

custom:
  serverless-offline:
    noPrependStageInUrl: true
  contentCompression: 1024
  apigwBinary:
    types:
      - "*/*"

package:
  excludeDevDependencies: true
  patterns:
    - "!node_modules/**"
    - "!**/*.ts"
    - "!**/*.html"
    - "!**/*.json"
    - "!**/*.scss"
    - "dist/**"
    - "!src/**"
    - "!e2e/**"
    - "angular.json"
    - "package.json"
    - "tsconfig.json"
    - "tsconfig.app.json"
    - "tsconfig.spec.json"
    - "tslint.json"
    - "README.md"
    - "!firebug-lite/**"
    - "!coverage/**"
    - "!.angular/**"
    - "!.vscode/**"
    - "node_modules/@vendia/**"
    - "node_modules/aws-serverless-express/**"
    - "node_modules/binary-case/**"
    - "node_modules/type-is/**"
    - "node_modules/media-typer/**"
    - "node_modules/mime-types/**"
    - "node_modules/mime-db/**"
```

lambda.js file

```
// Import the required modules
const awsServerlessExpress = require('aws-serverless-express');

// Define your MIME types
const binaryMimeTypes = [
    'application/javascript',
    'application/json',
    'application/octet-stream',
    'application/xml',
    'font/eot',
    'font/opentype',
    'font/otf',
    'image/jpeg',
    'image/png',
    'image/svg+xml',
    'text/comma-separated-values',
    'text/css',
    'text/html',
    'text/javascript',
    'text/plain',
    'text/text',
    'text/xml'
];

let server;

// Import the app from the ES module
import('./dist/seventeentest/server/server.mjs').then((app) => {
    // Create a server with the specified MIME types
    server = awsServerlessExpress.createServer(app.default, null, binaryMimeTypes);
}).catch((error) => {
    console.error('Failed to import app:', error);
});

// Export the universal function
exports.universal = (event, context) => {
    console.log(`EVENT: ${JSON.stringify(event)}`);
    if (!server) {
        console.error('Server is not initialized');
        return;
    }
    return awsServerlessExpress.proxy(server, event, context, 'PROMISE').promise;
};
```

But the deployment is failing and showing me the error

> {"message": "Internal server error"}

and the console is showing the errors

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
> favicon.ico:1  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a
> status of 502 ()   dev:1

Answer (score 0):

Solution over AWS using Serverless and Lambda

**server.ts**

```
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { CommonEngine } from '@angular/ssr';
import express from 'express';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import { dirname, join, resolve } from 'path';
import bootstrap from './src/main.server';

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by Serverless Functions.
export function app(): express.Express {      
  const server = express();
  const serverDistFolder = dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));
  const browserDistFolder = resolve(serverDistFolder, '../browser');
  const indexHtml = join(serverDistFolder, 'index.server.html');
  const commonEngine = new CommonEngine();
    
  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', browserDistFolder);
         
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(browserDistFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));
    
  // All regular routes use the Angular engine
  server.get('*', (req, res, next) => {       
    const { protocol, originalUrl, baseUrl, headers } = req;        
    commonEngine
      .render({
        bootstrap: bootstrap,
        documentFilePath: indexHtml,
        url: `${protocol}://${headers.host}${originalUrl}`,
        publicPath: browserDistFolder,
        providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: baseUrl }],
      })
      .then((html) => {              
        res.send(html)
      })
      .catch((err) => {            
        next(err)
      });
  });
    
  return server;
}

export * from './src/main.server';
```

**lambda.js**

```
const awsServerlessExpress = require('aws-serverless-express');
const awsServerlessExpressMiddleware = require('aws-serverless-express/middleware');
const binaryMimeTypes = [
  "application/javascript",
  "application/json",
  "application/octet-stream",
  "application/xml",
  "image/jpeg",
  "image/png",
  "image/webp",
  "image/gif",
  "text/comma-separated-values",
  "text/css",
  "text/html",
  "text/javascript",
  "text/plain",
  "text/text",
  "text/xml",
  "image/x-icon",
  "image/svg+xml",
  "application/x-font-ttf",
  "font/ttf",
  "font/otf",
  "font/woff",
  "font/woff2"
];

module.exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  console.log(`EVENT: ${JSON.stringify(event)}`);

  try {
    // Import the app from the ES module
    const server = await import('./dist/app-name/server/server.mjs');
    const app = await server.app();

    app.use(awsServerlessExpressMiddleware.eventContext());

    // Create a server with the specified MIME types
    const serverAws = awsServerlessExpress.createServer(app, null, binaryMimeTypes);

    if (!app) {
      console.error('Server is not initialized');
      return;
    } else {
      return awsServerlessExpress.proxy(serverAws, event, context, 'PROMISE').promise;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Failed to import app:', error);
  }
};
```

**serverless.yml**

```
service: service-name

frameworkVersion: '3'

plugins:
  - serverless-apigw-binary

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs20.x
  memorySize: 192
  timeout: 10
  region: us-east-1
  apiGateway:
    shouldStartNameWithService: true

package:
  excludeDevDependencies: true
  exclude:
    - ./**
    - '!node_modules/@vendia/**'
  include:
    - "node_modules/aws-serverless-express/**"
    - "node_modules/binary-case/**"
    - "node_modules/type-is/**"
    - "node_modules/media-typer/**"
    - "node_modules/mime-types/**"
    - "node_modules/mime-db/**"
    - "node_modules/@angular/ssr"
    - "node_modules/@codegenie/**"
    - "dist/**"
    - "lambda.js"

  functions:
    server:
    handler: lambda.handler
    events:
      - http: ANY /{proxy+}
      - http: ANY /

  resources:
    - ${file(resources.yml)}
```

Also in **angular.json** you shoud change this line

```
"prerender": false, //<-Change to false
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply. I tried implementing it but couldn't get it working.
[link]https://github.com/angelaphil/seventeen-test/tree/main
I am attaching my github implementation for reference. Please let me know where I am going wrong. It's just a basic angular 17 application ssr enabled with two mock routes.

Comment: How are you carrying out the deployment of your application? Are you using IAC? I see in the code that you are not importing the resources.yml file into your serverless.yml which I use to deploy my infrastructure as code. You also need a script or automate a GitHub action to carry out the deployment. On the other hand, you may be configuring your infrastructure manually using the AWS console. Basically could you give more details about what error you are getting?

Comment: I have cloudformation and aws extensions in my vscode. I first run "ng build". Then I deploy it using "serverless deploy". On deployment it generates endpoints which i use in cloudfront. In this case, endpoints are returning "{"message": "Internal server error"}". idk if it's right method but it worked well for me in angular 16. Also if you can, please let me know about any step by step guides to deploy angular 17 ssr to aws lambda + cron to keep it active or beanstalk. I couldn't find any sample examples to get going.